# ViewBox Stretch blurs the controls

Tags: c#, wpf, blur, viewbox, stretching

[image: ViewBox Stretch blur]

ToolTip with numbers is a child UserControl, which is added to Canvas.
Canvas is a child of the ViewBox.
In order to scale the contents of the Canvas resizing control.
The problem is that ToolTip getting blurred.
ToolTip itself consists only of vector elements (without pictures)

How to make ViewBox scale without these artifacts?
Layout Rounding does not help

Comment: Have you tried setting SnapsToDevicePixels="True"?

Comment: @DarkIce Does not help.