# Dynamically change the size of the control?

Tags: c#, wpf, resize, controls, overriding

I created a class derived from `UserControl`
My task is to control the size proportions of height and width. (If the container is inserted to control will resize it.) I need the control to be strictly square.

What should be done to change the new dimensions of the control? `SizeChangedEventArgs.NewSize` property is read only.

```
private void MyControl_SizeChanged(object sender,SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewSize.Height!=e.NewSize.Width)
    {
        // to-do ?
    }
}
```

Width and Heigth in my case are NaN since the mode is set to Auto. I can not change manually Width or  Height property since then Control will automatically fixed size and does not change when you scale grid in which it is placed.

Comment: Do you want to change the Width to the Height or Height to Width

Comment: @SonerGönül you forgot to edit the code block again :)

Comment: @Default Damn! I just woke up a few minutes ago. I need a coffee maybe.

Comment: @sa_ddam213
Yes, but the Width and Heigth in my case are NaN
Since the mode is set to Auto.
I can not change manually since then Control is a fixed size and is not affected by scaling grid in which it is placed.

Comment: @SonerGönül well, I got your back and fixed it :)

Comment: @SonerGönül, you should add that info to the question.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a control to be exactly square, the easiest way is to use a binding like so:

```
<Control Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ActualHeight}"/>
```

**Edit** 
OK, seems like you can go well with your event handler:

```
FrameworkElement control =(sender as FrameworkElement);
double longerSideLength = (control.Width >= control.Height ? control.Width : control.Height);
control.Width = longerSideLength;
control.Height = longerSideLength;
```

You might want to add some validation to that to reduce call count...

Comment: the situation is a little more difficult, I want to kind of uniform.
if (w> h) w = h;
if (h> w) h = w;

Comment: Would it helpt to put your control in a [viewbox](http://wpftutorial.net/ViewBox.html)?

Comment: I used at the beginning ViewBox for this purpose
but I had to stop using it cause is described here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957794/viewbox-stretch-blurs-the-controls